# Output Printing After Raw Input: Out of Order in Python

Tags: python-2.7

When I try to run the following function, the output is incorrect. I've got print statements before a raw_input variable. It's asking for the raw_input variable and then printing the statements, like so:

```
    def getPlayerBid(hand1, bidList):

        print ""            
        print 'Your Cards: ' + " ".join(hand1)
        print 'Previous bids: '
        for item in bidList:
            print item
        print ""
        bid1 = int(raw_input('What\'s your bid?(Enter 0 to pass): '))
    ....
```

This is the output:

> ```
> What's your bid?(Enter 0 to pass): 
> Your Cards: KH 2H 2D 5C 4D
> Previous bids:
> ```

Any help with what I am doing wrong here would be great!

Comment: what is your question? Your code does exactly what it should when I run it. It prints the lines then the `raw_input` is executed

Comment: Please fix your code indentation (eg: there's no indent after your `for` statement)

Comment: Padraic I know I don't know why it's giving me the output listed above. Instead of printing the cards and previous bids first, it's prompting for the raw input and then printing the lines above, not letting me enter the input. Could be canopy? Not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me once.  Lines weren't printing in the order that they were being executed in the code.  I was baffled.  Then I realized that I was still piping the output to sort.